# I am trying to find specific type fonts

Tags: typography

I created a book cover and while I have been waiting for approval the file along with the backup has crashed and I am rebuilding the cover. I can not find the fonts used. Can someone please help me find the actual

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *please* take a look around [tour] to see who and what we are as a community; please also peruse [ask] and [answer] a question so that you can understand what make a good query for **GD.SE** and how to frame it for best responses. Your query, as written, is unclear, appears to be textually incomplete, and is missing screenshots or any descriptions of what you've tried so far, so that we've literally ***no*** entry points for even *trying* to start helping you as this is written now. I strongly suggest reading [ask] and editing your post a bit!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the PDF of the work, try to check in Acrobat what fonts it has. It's in document properties. You can read a list of used fonts.

Fonts can even be embedded, if that was not prevented when the document was created. There's a good reason not to embed fonts. Distributing fonts is a form of software piracy. For this reason for ex. Adobe doesn't allow users to embed its own paid fonts.

Many users intentionally replace texts with images of the texts (=convert to curves or rasterize) to avoid piracy talks and comments "we do not have that font"  from people who try to read the PDF. If that's your case, you can let Font Identifier websites to identify the fonts from sharp enough text images.

Those sites, for ex. FontSquirrel and WhatTheFont know tens of thousands of fonts, but none of them know all. Many fonts which are freeware or sold by small companies, stay unidentified.